How to extract strings after specific symbols in one column and separate to multiple rows?
I have data that contains the nearest gene sets, including their genomic region and strand, in one column.
I want to make a new column for the single gene extracted from that column and separate them into multiple rows. Gene names are located after |+| or |-|.
Original data
original <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2), distance = c(0, 167155), 
    nearestTargetGeneAnchorB = c("chr1:248838178-248849517|+|ZNF672,chr1:248826377-248826443|+|MIR3124,chr1:248810452-248825955|-|SH3BP5L", 
        "chr1:248323630-248324568|-|OR2M7,chr1:248294616-248295578|-|OR2T12")), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
        -2L))

How can I transform the table to this?
fixed <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2), distance = c(0, 
    0, 0, 167155, 167155), nearestTargetGeneAnchorB = c("chr1:248838178-248849517|+|ZNF672,chr1:248826377-248826443|+|MIR3124,chr1:248810452-248825955|-|SH3BP5L", 
    "chr1:248838178-248849517|+|ZNF672,chr1:248826377-248826443|+|MIR3124,chr1:248810452-248825955|-|SH3BP5L", 
    "chr1:248838178-248849517|+|ZNF672,chr1:248826377-248826443|+|MIR3124,chr1:248810452-248825955|-|SH3BP5L", 
    "chr1:248323630-248324568|-|OR2M7,chr1:248294616-248295578|-|OR2T12", 
    "chr1:248323630-248324568|-|OR2M7,chr1:248294616-248295578|-|OR2T13"), 
    ...4 = c("ZNF672", "MIR3124", "SH3BP5L", "OR2M7", "OR2T13")), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
        -5L))


library(tidyr)

original %>% 
  separate_rows(nearestTargetGeneAnchorB, sep = ",") %>% 
  mutate(variable = sub(".*\\|", "", nearestTargetGeneAnchorB)) %>% 
  select(-nearestTargetGeneAnchorB)
  # A tibble: 5 × 3
     id distance variable
  <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>   
1     1        0 ZNF672  
2     1        0 MIR3124 
3     1        0 SH3BP5L 
4     2   167155 OR2M7   
5     2   167155 OR2T12 


Thank you, it worked! Although I also wanted to keep the original column, it is not a big deal for the analysis for now. Thank you!

Just remove last line, the select part.

Split on ",", then on "|", get the 3rd item - "Gene", and add as new row, group by id:
library(data.table)

setDT(original)

original[, unlist(tstrsplit(nearestTargetGeneAnchorB, split = ",")), by = id 
         ][, .(Gene = unlist(tstrsplit(V1, split = "|", fixed = TRUE, keep = 3))),
           by = id ] 

#      id    Gene
#   <num>  <char>
#1:     1  ZNF672
#2:     1 MIR3124
#3:     1 SH3BP5L
#4:     2   OR2M7
#5:     2  OR2T12


Thank you for the comment! I tried this, and I got the error message below: did I do something wrong?    > diffev[, unlist(tstrsplit(nearestTargetGeneAnchorA, split = ",")), by = id

][, .(Gene = unlist(tstrsplit(V1, split = "|", fixed = TRUE, keep = 3))),
by = id ]
Error in as.vector(x, "list") :
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'

